# Invalid Variant Operation error

Tags: delphi

I have an error in my button click, and I can't figure out how to resolve it.

This is my code:

```
if (ovElements.item(i).name = 'add') and    
(ovElements.item(i).type = 'button') and    
(ovElements.item(i).Value = ' + ') then    
ovElements.item(i).Click;
```

This is the markup:

```
<td width="20" align="left"><input class="button" style="width: 30px;" 
 name="add" value=" + " onclick="addLvl();" type="button"></td>
```

And it gives this error:

```
Invalid Variant Operation Error
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: I fixed up your code to be readable, but I wasn't sure if Chytry is suppose to be your closing tag?

Comment: When you say it gives an Invalid Variant Operation order, do you mean it raises an exception with "Invalid Variant Operation Error" as the message text?  What class is the exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess:

ovElements.item(i).Value is probably a Variant.  If a variant contains a null value you will get that error when you compare it to a string.

Make sure ovElements.item(i) doesn't contain a null value before comparing it.

Answer (score 1):

It means an operation on a variant which is executed is invalid. This happens, for example, when a variant containing some text is divided by an integer. Clearly this cannot work, but since the compiler can't check this, it is a runtime error.

Use a temporary variable for the 3 parts in your if statement to see better on which line the error is raised. Then inspect what the values are and what the invalid operation is.

Answer (score 1):

You can save "ovElements.item(i)" to a local variable and then split your code into multiple line.

```
obj = ovElements.item(i);
if obj <> nil then
try
  if obj.name = 'add' then
    if obj.type = 'button' then
      if obj.value = ' + ' then    
        obj.click;
except
end;
```

In this way you can see which line causes this problem.